# Monitor a folder on an azure disk from an azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-disk

We have a legacy app hosted on an azure VM which will periodically output files to a file share (SMB) which is located on an azure disk. The legacy app is not "Azure Aware" so can only output to a share.

The legacy app runs within a virtual infrastructure so everything is in azure and secured against the azure active directory.

I'm trying to automate some processes based on these files and so would like to be able to trigger an azure function when a new file arrives and read the contents of that file.

Is it possible to read the contents of an azure disk from an azure function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure functions doesn't support file system triggers/bindings(since you mentioned a VM), the full list of what's supported can be viewed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings). A workaround i'd suggest would be to use logic apps connector for Filesystems (supports Azure hosted VMs), the full documentation for this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector), then you can add the Functions into the process